# Java: LinkedList reversal in chunks

Tags: java, algorithm

If you are provided the head of a linked list, and are asked to reverse every k sequence of nodes, how might this be done in Java? e.g., `a->b->c->d->e->f->g->h` with k = 3 would be `c->b->a->f->e->d->h->g->f`

Any general help or even pseudocode would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: k = 3 would be c->b->a->f->e->d->h->g ?

Comment: Recursive uses extra space O(k) where k may be n. See my O(n) time, O(1) space solution.

Comment: @kasavbere You've done a bit of spamming here, imho. You posted your answer and explained it well; there's no need to reply to almost every answer just to point to yours. We can see your answer without that.

Comment: @yshavit, such was not my intent. I only replied to the posts that are subpar to point out where they come short. I don't like telling people what they are doing wrong without telling them what "right" looks like; so I point to my posted reply. This is a O(n) time, O(1) space algorithm. People can solve the basic problem where there is no `k` (or say `k=n`) and then modify it a bit to solve the case where `k<=n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `k` is expected to be reasonably small, I would just go for the simplest thing: ignore the fact that it's a linked list at all, and treat each subsequence as just an array-type thing of things to be reversed.

So, if your linked list's node class is a `Node<T>`, create a `Node<?>[]` of size `k`. For each segment, load `k` `Nodes` into the array list, then just reverse their elements with a simple `for` loop. In pseudocode:

```
// reverse the elements within the k nodes
for i from 0 to k/2:
    nodeI = segment[i]
    nodeE = segment[segment.length-i-1]
    tmp = nodeI.elem
    nodeI.elem = nodeE.elem
    nodeE.elem = tmp
```

Pros: very simple, O(N) performance, takes advantage of an easily recognizable reversing algorithm.

Cons: requires a `k`-sized array (just once, since you can reuse it per segment)

Also note that this means that each `Node` doesn't move in the list, only the objects the `Node` holds. This means that each `Node` will end up holding a different item than it held before. This could be fine or not, depending on your needs.

Comment: Erm and of course, you could also just do a swap of the two nodes, Node and all. That's what I get for answering while watching hockey...

Comment: What if k is not small? The problem can be solved in place in O(n) time and O(1) space. See my solution

Comment: @kasavbere Yup, definitely can be. Your solution is a tad more complex than mine, though, so if you know (from whatever source the req for the function came from) that k is known to be small, I would say go for the simpler code. But you're right that it has limitations, which is why I called them out explicitly (twice, even).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty high-level, but I think it'll give some guidance.

I'd have a helper method like `void swap3(Node first, Node last)` that take three elements at an arbitrary position of the list and reverses them. This shouldn't be hard, and could could be done recursively (swap the outer elements, recurse on the inner elements until the size of the list is 0 or 1). Now that I think of it, you could generalize this into `swapK()` easily if you're using recursion.

Once that is done, then you can just walk along your linked list and call `swapK()` every `k` nodes. If the size of the list isn't divisble by `k`, you could either just not swap that last bit, or reverse the last `length%k` nodes using your swapping technique.

Answer (score 1):

TIME O(n); SPACE O(1)

A usual requirement of list reversal is that you do it in O(n) time and O(1) space. This eliminates recursion or stack or temporary array (what if K==n?), etc.
Hence the challenge here is to modify an in-place reversal algorithm to account for the `K` factor. Instead of `K` I use `dist` for distance.

Here is a simple in-place reversal algorithm: Use three pointers to walk the list in place: `b` to point to the head of the new list; `c` to point to the moving head of the unprocessed list; `a` to facilitate swapping between `b` and `c`.

```
 A->B->C->D->E->F->G->H->I->J->L //original
 A<-B<-C<-D    E->F->G->H->I->J->L //during processing
          ^    ^
          |    |
          b    c
 `a` is the variable that allow us to move `b` and `c` without losing either of
  the lists.

Node simpleReverse(Node n){//n is head
if(null == n || null == n.next)
   return n;
Node a=n, b=a.next, c=b.next;
a.next=null; b.next=a;
while(null != c){
   a=c;
   c=c.next;
   a.next=b;
   b=a;
}
return b;
}
```

To convert the `simpleReverse` algorithm to a `chunkReverse` algorithm, do following:

1] After reversing the first chunk, set `head` to `b`; `head` is the permanent head of the resulting list.

2] for all the other chunks, set `tail.next` to `b`; recall that `b` is the head of the chunk just processed.

some other details:

3] If the list has one or fewer nodes or the dist is 1 or less, then return the list without processing.

4] use a counter `cnt` to track when `dist` consecutive nodes have been reversed.

5] use variable `tail` to track the tail of the chunk just processed and `tmp` to track the tail of the chunk being processed.

6] notice that before a chunk is processed, it's head, which is bound to become its tail, is the first node you encounter: so, set it to `tmp`, which is a temporary tail.

```
public Node reverse(Node n, int dist) {
  if(dist<=1 || null == n || null == n.right) 
      return n;
  Node tail=n, head=null, tmp=null;
  while(true) {
      Node a=n, b=a.right; n=b.right;
      a.right=null; b.right=a;
      int cnt=2;
      while(null != n && cnt < dist) {
          a=n; n=n.right; a.right=b; b=a;
          cnt++;
      }
      if(null == head) head = b;
      else {
          tail.right=b;tail=tmp;
      }
      tmp=n;
      if(null == n) return head;
      if(null == n.right) {
          tail.right=n;
          return head;
      }
  }//true
  }
```

Comment: assuming the first algo is correct, why don't you just use it in reverse?

Comment: `assuming the first algo is correct`? It's easy to test. Write a `int` LinkedList class with an `insert`, a `print` and this `reverse` function. And then in the `main()` method fill the list with `int`s from `1 to x=26` or whatever. Then do reverse for different values of `dist`. As for `why don't you just use it in reverse?` it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: i mean you modify `simpleReverse` such that it reverses from one index position to another (and keep an additional pointer). then you iteratively call `simpleReverse` as much as you need with different indexes using the last pointer returned. Something like that...

Comment: Node simpleReverse(Node from, int len, Node NextFrom);

Comment: This is basically what `reverse` is doing. But sure, you can refactor the code to extract `simpleReverse`. Good observation!

Answer (score 1):

E.g. by Common Lisp

```
(defun rev-k (k sq)
  (if (<= (length sq) k)
      (reverse sq)
      (concatenate 'list (reverse (subseq sq 0 k)) (rev-k k (subseq sq k)))))
```

other way
E.g. by F# use Stack

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let rev_k k (list:'T list)  =
  seq {
    let stack = new Stack<'T>()
    for x in list do
      stack.Push(x)
      if stack.Count = k then
        while stack.Count > 0 do
          yield stack.Pop()
    while stack.Count > 0 do
      yield stack.Pop()
  }
  |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Recursion uses too much space. See my solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack and recursively remove k items from the list, push them to the stack then pop them and add them in place. Not sure if it's the best solution, but stacks offer a proper way of inverting things. Notice that this also works if instead of a list you had a queue.
Simply dequeue k items, push them to the stack, pop them from the stack and enqueue them :)

Comment: Recursion uses too much space. See my solution

Answer (score 0):

This implementation uses ListIterator class:

```
LinkedList<T> list;
//Inside the method after the method's parameters check
ListIterator<T> it = (ListIterator<T>) list.iterator(); 
ListIterator<T> reverseIt =  (ListIterator<T>) list.listIterator(k); 

for(int i = 0; i< (int) k/2; i++ )
{
    T element  = it.next();
    it.set(reverseIt.previous());
    reverseIt.set(element);
}
```

Comment: too much space. See my solution